# Is there an expression or word to describe a person who does something that is unnecessary?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word or phrase that describes a person who:

1. Does something that is *not important* or is unnecessary AND
2. Does not do something that is *important* or necessary?

I would appreciate it if the word can be slotted into the following gap:

> Ali is a ____ person. He doesn't always get his priorities right. He
>   always does things that are not important and forgets to do things
>   that are important.

Thank you very much.

Comment: er, can anyone tell me what the downvote for?

Comment: Well, it isn’t even phrased in English.  You’ve done no research. You offer no suggestions. And you’re just looking for a bad word to call someone whose behavior you disapprove of.

Comment: @tchrist Well, I beg to voice against your comment 'Well, it isn’t even phrased in English. You’ve done no research. You offer no suggestions. And you’re just looking for a bad word to call someone whose behavior you disapprove of'. I google for keywords like person, necessary, unnecessary, description but could not find any. Maybe, you can suggest which words I should use to search for it?

Comment: While I think this is a good question, the bad grammar greatly detracts from it.

Comment: meta discussion here: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4761/what-to-do-about-good-questions-that-have-bad-grammar-poor-english

Comment: I am annoyed by the grammar of the title of your question.

Comment: I suggest your read our [Help] to understand the scope of this site. I think you might find a better home for your questions on [ell.se].

Comment: Come on, people, give the questioner a break. The grammar isn't perfect, but it's easily good enough to get the question across.

Comment: @ErikKowal See the metadiscussion.

Comment: I'm with @ErikKowal. The English is hardly atrocious and I don't see why his presumed intent (to find a word abuse Ali) should matter at all. I did the same search the OP said he has done and no words of any use appeared in the first page. It's clear his English is not perfect so I imagine it's not easy trawling through unrelated results looking for a word. Instead of castigating isn't it just better to assist?

Comment: @Frank - This comes in the context of a lot of ELL questions coming through here, and I guess people are sick of it.

Comment: @user1068446 It's one thing to be sick of it, you can just move along to the next question or you can assist the OP to improve the grammar in their question or you can directly edit their question or just ignore the small errors and provide an answer or vote to close but it's a whole other ball game to take the piss out of someone who is trying to write/speak English, presumably, as best as they can.

Comment: @Frank - Additionally - you can downvote the question and explain why it's not well received.

Comment: @user1068446 Good point, noted.

Comment: Procrastinator.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that this person does not have his [*priorities*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/priorities) straight, where priorities are *concerns established in order of importance*.

> To identify, *prioritize*, and coordinate short-term Bacillus anthracis bioterrorism research for public health response, the Centers for Disease Control and Prevention (CDC) convened a meeting in Atlanta on December 10-11, 2001, to obtain input on research *priorities* and improve coordination with federal partners and other stakeholders.

Answer (score 1):

Ali is an [***irresponsible***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/irresponsible) person.

> ***irresponsible*** : 2. Lacking a sense of responsibility; unreliable or untrustworthy.

Answer (score 1):

A **careless** person at work, suggests someone who is possibly distracted, forgets to do things, and lacks the basic skills to organize his/her work carefully and efficiently.

> Careless:  *showing a lack of attention*. <sub>[G.D](https://www.google.com/search?num=30&rlz=1C1AFAB_en___IT446&es_sm=122&q=careless%20define&oq=careless%20define&gs_l=serp.3..0j0i22i30l9.18662.20613.0.21526.7.7.0.0.0.0.179.1118.0j7.7.0....0...1c.1.43.serp..0.7.1111.ZxQCZUagCkU)</sub>
>   *not taking care* <sub>[T.F.D](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/careless)</sub>
>   not exact, accurate, or *thorough* <sub>[D.C](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/careless)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I would say that Ali is an [**incoherent**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/incoherent+?s=t) person.

> **incoherent**: irrational; without logical or meaningful connection; confused; disordered.

"*Ali is an incoherent (or [**illogical**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/illogical)) person. He always does not get his priorities right. He always does things that are not important, and forgets to do things that are important*."

Comment: Is this a pointed dig at the OP?

Comment: @user1068446 Why's that? Do you think there's some kinda coherence in someone who does things that are unimportant or unnecessary, and forgets to do what is considered important and necessary?

Comment: @user1068446 - that was unnecessary (unless you were being serious?)

Comment: @medica You bet I was. Does that sound that extraordinary that someone who does things in a way contrary to common sense might be considered "incoherent?"

Comment: @Elian - no, I wasn't disagreeing with *your* answer, only wondering why user 1068446 made that comment. I don't think you were attacking OP (which was user's connotation); you're not like that. Wanted to let him know that. PS not my downvote.

Comment: I think irrational or illogical really fits the meaning nicely.

Answer (score -1):

**Procrastinate** (*to put off intentionally and habitually*) may be a good starting point [Merriam Webster Procrastinate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/procrastinate)

This gives you a number of phrases you could use

> Ali is a procrastinating person
>
> Ali is a procrastinator
>
> Ali is always procrastinating

Answer (score -1):

I would say:

> Ali is a superfluous person. He doesn't always get his priorities right. He always does things that are not important and forgets to do things that are important.

Although a better sentence is perhaps;

> As a person, Ali is superfluous to requirements.

See this definition:

> superfluous
>   **suːˈpəːflʊəs,sjuːadjective**
>
> unnecessary, especially through being more than enough.
>   "the purchaser should avoid asking for superfluous information"

Comment: In terms of style, this answer was/is very poorly formatted.

Comment: I'd agree, first post and all that. As an aside, what did you think of superfluous as an answer?

Comment: I don't think superfluous works well for this one. Or rather it a *superfluous person* could mean either a person who acts superfluously or a person whose existence is unnecessary. Forbid the second thought. So a dangerous construction.

Answer (score -2):

ali is an unorganized person. He doesn't always get his priorities right. He always does things that are not important and forgets to do things that are important.

Comment: Hello. You can strengthen your answer by including an explanation of why _unorganized_ his a good answer to the poster's fill-in-the-blank question. In supporting your answer, consider citing suitable authority such as one or more relevant definitions from a dictionary. Thanks!